# OPC UA UserIdentity

Tags: c#, .net, opc-ua

I am trying to connect to an OPC-UA Server using the credentials that I have set.

//user

```
var user = new UserIdentity("admin", "admin");
```

//session

```
var session = Session.Create(config, new ConfiguredEndpoint(null, selectedEndpoint, EndpointConfiguration.Create(config)), false, "", (uint)6000, user, null).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

I always get the error:

> Failed to connect Certificate is not trusted.

When I login anonymously it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use a username and password in OPC UA, they need to be encrypted during transport.  This encryption is done using an X.509 certificate.  Therefore, you need to exchange **and trust** X.509 certificates with the OPC UA server even if you do not encrypt the rest of your session.

Check your API for how to do this.  Your certificate must also be trusted on the server.